# Wordpress emails going to spam

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, gmail, spam

I have been having a lot of issues with emails from our servers going to SPAM. I cant find out why, I am not on any blacklist and we have the SPF/DKIM records validated.

Below is a transcripts of our emails...

```
    Received: from host.ilovenz.me (host.ilovenz.me [96.30.1.56])
    by relay-6.us-west-2.relay-prod (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 34DBA460BBA
    for <20g0dnL7Le4vW8@dkimvalidator.com>; Sun, 26 Feb 2017 03:31:39 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=ilovenz.me;
     s=default; h=MIME-Version:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:Date:
    Subject:To:Sender:From:Reply-To:Message-ID:Cc:Content-ID:Content-Description:
    Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:
    In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:
    List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive;
    bh=dKce1b0OIqr1iFXsTI1PsQWwBft9eaJeSIwAbZhxRp0=; b=VOkfOW7ftU5bxGSL0Q9D+2tvB2
    nGx9pmAcaRGzrFlwOLg8IrYYmU0h8PWqPTQ/4mD26BJCAEUdAYjXaKYl9ovhGWJMW9qAfK4Hy7JXk
    aQDJOw6jBKHM5aRbgm9aIuXrPEe4+AngMao85vH9PKRTBQxegl2nJYX+JApr4MHf1S14uCyEYAcD7
    nJwlrZJ32VAxn2gz1rDeevkTSptaSqpgX4EURzZDR/2osv53Np2//F+5qCTFabvwr9qe5RyiKsV5g
    56TP/Ym1R4a25QzOg4yLiqr0ZlBh4zTB6lIGpfF7NWRtOPW49c02rEO8raOV3lgfXWWi+kD4NO1fy
    Xw8Tljtw==;
Received: from host.ilovenz.me ([96.30.1.56]:48972 helo=localhost)
    by host.ilovenz.me with esmtpa (Exim 4.88)
    (envelope-from <hello@ilovenz.me>)
    id 1chpYg-0000eR-6I
    for 20g0dnL7Le4vW8@dkimvalidator.com; Sun, 26 Feb 2017 16:31:38 +1300
X-Mailer: Postman SMTP 1.7.2 for WordPress (https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/)
From: ilovenz <hello@ilovenz.me>
Sender: hello@ilovenz.me
To: 20g0dnL7Le4vW8@dkimvalidator.com
Subject: [I Love New Zealand] Activate your account
Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2017 03:31:38 +0000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - host.ilovenz.me
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - dkimvalidator.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - ilovenz.me
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: host.ilovenz.me: authenticated_id: hello@ilovenz.me
X-Authenticated-Sender: host.ilovenz.me: hello@ilovenz.me
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 

Thanks for registering!=0A=0ATo complete the activation of your account,=
 go to the following link: https://ilovenz.me/activate/kWwH8aMmTTYQCeii6=
nHDAZ1T3Lxw0QSr/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you are using an unusual TLD and you have the word 'love' in it. I had a similair problem with a poker site.

Comment: Thanks, have decided to move to gsuite and now they are sending out the emails there isn't an issue.